# jQuery trying to get value of one select option based on result of another select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

have the below Javascript already, and a couple of Select Groups.

When selecting one of the options in one of the groups, it fills the relavent text box with the text() of that option, and the single ID text box with the val().
This all works fine.

but where I am stuck is that , I need to have it  , so that when I select an option in one of the select groups, it looks up the option with the same value in the other select group, and then displays the text of that option in the relevant box.

e.g. 
If I pick 'Option1', it displays 'Option1' in the first text box, and 'item1' in the second text box (and 1 in the ID text box).
If I pick 'item3', it displays 'item3' in the second text box, and 'option3' in the first text box (and 3 in the ID text box).

I got as far as using:

```
var disp = $('#selItem').find('option[value=1]').text();
alert(disp);
```

but can't get the dynamic value to go with 'option[value=1]'.

I tried:

```
var thisValue = $('#txtID').val( $(this).val() ); 
alert(thisValue);
```

but it responds with `[object Object]`.

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../Generic/JAVASCRIPT/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        .InputField{ width:150px;}
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready( function() 
        {
            $('#selOption').change( function() 
                {
                    $('#txtID').val( $(this).val() );
                    $('#txtOption').val($('#selOption option:selected').html());
                }
            );

            $('#selItem').change( function() 
                {
                    $('#txtID').val( $(this).val() );
                    $('#txtItem').val($('#selItem option:selected').html());
                }
            );
        })  
    </script>
</head>


<body>
    <select id="selOption" class="InputField">
        <option value="" disabled="" selected="" style="display:none;">Select One...</option>
        <option value="1">Option1</option>
        <option value="2">Option2</option>
        <option value="3">Option3</option>                      
    </select>

    <select id="selItem" class="InputField">
        <option value="" disabled="" selected="" style="display:none;">Select One...</option>
        <option value="1">item1</option>
        <option value="2">item2</option>
        <option value="3">item3</option>                        
    </select>

    </br>

    <input type="text" name="txtOption" id="txtOption" placeholder="Which Option is it?" class="InputField"/>
    <input type="text" name="txtItem" id="txtItem" placeholder="Which item is it?" class="InputField"/>

    </br></br>

    <input type="text" name="txtID" id="txtID" placeholder="ID Number" class="InputField"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$('#selItem').val($(this).val());` works like a charm in firefox...what browser are you using?

Comment: I generally work with Chrome, one of the advantages of not being a 'pro' web developer, I get much more control over which browsers my code runs on.

Comment: i gave you an answer...try it out and give feedback :)

Comment: In my answer I also change the selected option, was that desired or just needed to get the text value to insert in the field under?

Comment: It wasn't strictly needed, but only because I hadn't considered that. It's actually quite useful for what I want to do with this going forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#selOption').change(function () {
        $('#txtID').val($(this).val());
        $('#txtOption').val($('#selOption option:selected').text());
        $('#selItem').val($(this).val());
        $('#txtItem').val($('#selItem option:selected').text());
    });

    $('#selItem').change(function () {
        $('#txtID').val($(this).val());
        $('#txtItem').val($('#selItem option:selected').text());
        $('#selOption').val($(this).val());
        $('#txtOption').val($('#selOption option:selected').text());
    });
})
```

### **Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ajTH9/1/)**

Comment: In the question, it says that selecting from one menu looks up the corresponding element in the other menu and puts it in the text field. This answer also changes the selected element in the other menu as a side effect -- is that what you wanted as well?

Comment: @Barmar, good point. I just thought OP wanted that. Asked that to OP now also.

Answer (score 2):

It's just:

```
var thisValue = $(this).val();
```

When you call `.val()` with an argument, as in:

```
var thisValue = $("#txtID").val($(this).val());
```

it doesn't return the value, it returns the jQuery object, to allow for chaining.

To use this to get the text of the other `select`, do:

```
var itemText = $("#selItem option[value=" + thisValue + "]").text();
```

Comment: great explanation there, I didn't realise about the difference between the object and the value in that way. A bit more reading required I think.

Answer (score 1):

This is totally normal behavior that it returns `Object`. This is natural jQuery chaining, so You could use something like `$(this).val(something).hide();`

Please note that `$(selector).val('something')` sets up value of selected object and returns that object. If You would like to get value, You have to use `val()` without argument.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('#selOption').change( function(){
    $('#txtID').val( $(this).val() );
    $('#txtOption').val($('#selOption option:selected').html());
    $('#selItem').val($(this).val());
    if(!changed){
        changed = true; //preventing recursion
        $('#selItem').trigger('change'); //fire change, to update text field
    } else {
        changed = false;                        
    }
});
```

works like a charm in my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/FPvxB/

Comment: cheers for that. I like the option of building it as a function and using .trigger() to 'trigger' the change. I've learned something else new today.